# Combine observables from valuechanges and statuschanges reactive form with rxjs in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to combine the `valueChanges` and `statusChanges` into one subscription cause i wanna do some logic when any of the 2 changes.

I'm trying to use `combineLatest` which should fire as soon as one of the observables gets an update. The problem i'm having is rxjs is giving me a warning that `valueChanges` and `statusChanges` arent subscribeable.

`this.control` is an angular `FormControl`

I'm using `"rxjs": "^6.3.3"`

This is the error message i'm getting in my console.

```
TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:41)
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:11)
    at CombineLatestSubscriber.push.../angular-shared-lib/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/observable/combineLatest.js.CombineLatestSubscriber._complete (combineLatest.js:62)
    at CombineLatestSubscriber.push.../angular-shared-lib/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.complete (Subscriber.js:66)
    at Observable._subscribe (subscribeToArray.js:8)
    at Observable.push.../angular-shared-lib/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:43)
    at Observable.push.../angular-shared-lib/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:29)
    at CombineLatestOperator.push.../angular-shared-lib/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/observable/combineLatest.js.CombineLatestOperator.call (combineLatest.js:32)
    at Observable.push.../angular-shared-lib/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:24)
    at FormErrorComponent.push.../angular-shared-lib/dist/fesm5/mymodule.js.FormErrorComponent.ngOnInit (mymodule.js:738)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:22099)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:23363)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:23325)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:23959)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23919)
```

This is the current code i'm using:

```
import { combineLatest, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Input() control: AbstractControl = new FormControl();

combineLatest(
  this.control.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(null)),
  this.control.statusChanges.pipe(startWith(null)),
).subscribe(() => {
  if (!this.control.valid) {
    this.setErrors();
  } else {
    this.showErrors = false;
  }
})
```

I also tried without the `startWith` pipe, tried putting them in an array, i tried a bunch but keep getting the `You provided an invalid object` message. Does anybody know why rxjs isn't able to subscribe to these angular observables? And how to make it work? Ofcourse I can easily make another subscription and solve my issues like that. But I wanna do this clean and am confused why this isn't working.

Comment: What is `this.control`?

Comment: Updated my question, it's an angular FormControl

Comment: What you have seems fine, so the error is probably not comming from this code snippet

Comment: Yes also tried that by putting it into an array.

Comment: I agree with martin; either you're not receiving a FormControl or the error is thrown from somewhere else

Comment: Updated the error message. I thought it worked like this too but it's rly where my error is coming from.

Comment: Could you please share with us what is the parameter you're passing exactly to the `control` input from the parent? I think your problem is there!

Comment: The error is comming from `combineLatest` but it looks like it's not this one. You're already piping `valueChanges` and `statusChanges` so they definitelly return Observables. Maybe try creating a simple stackblitz that replicated this issue.

Comment: It was this piece of code 100%. idk why `combineLatest` just doesn't seems to work as expected. it's why i asked this question. removing it and replacing with 2 seperate subscribers removed the error after all and works as expected.

Comment: It was an issue with a linked library and multiple rxjs packages. Fixed it by setting correct paths in tsconfig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments on your question, I think the wrong observable comes from the parent component (and exactly from the value you pass to the `control` input), which causes this error on runtime.

I replicated the same use-case on this working [stackBiltz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mksmrh), which is working without any issue.

```js
@Input() control: AbstractControl = new FormControl();

ngOnInit() {
  combineLatest([
    this.control.valueChanges,
    this.control.statusChanges
  ]).subscribe(() => {
    if (this.control.valid) {
      console.log('SUCESS');
    } else {
      console.log('ERROR');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Jup, this is the exact same code i use, i'm wondering if some other funky stuff is going on with rxjs

Comment: It was an issue with a linked library. there were multiple rxjs packages available which cause an issue. fixed it by setting my paths correctly in tsconfig

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you need combine latest.
Maybe try merge instead?

```ts
merge(
  this.control.valueChanges,
  this.control.statusChanges
).subscribe(_ => {
  if (!this.control.valid) {
    this.setErrors();
  } else {
    this.showErrors = false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Also tried with merge, get the same error.